# What to do if I suspect a website I visit and link to was compromised via an XSS?

Tags: web-browser, javascript

EDIT: The script has been removed and apparently the vulnerability has been patched.

My employer links to this resource:

```
http://www.myplan.com/
```

I recently noticed a JavaScript alert was added into to main landing page: "31337"

More likely bored, soon to be fired programmer or malicious attacker?

In either case is there anything I should do about it?

Comment: If you just browse the site without entering any sensitive data into it nor do you have an account there, I wouldn't worry about it. They have [contact email addresses](http://www.myplan.com/contact.php) on their "about us" page, you could tell them they got compromised if you want to be nice.

Comment: Are you sure it was a XSS problem? Could the coder have placed an alert for testing purposes? It's bad form, but lots of devs test problems in production.

Comment: @Neil It can be in the page source and still be an XSS attack. This class of attacks is known as persistent XSS attacks

Comment: Good point @limbenjamin. Deleted my prior comment.

Comment: @André except of course if it redirects you in the process and has a 0day browser exploit inserted into it.

Comment: @LucasKauffman pretty unlikely. If you had a browser zero-day and malicious intentions you surely wouldn't just throw it out in the wild like that, keeping it for targeted attacks seems better.

Comment: @André maybe for a 0day, but maybe there was other malicious code? My point is that just stating "your fine because you didn't enter any data" is too limited.

Comment: @LucasKauffman yeah, that's why I said "*I* wouldn't worry about it" - I never said there wasn't any risk, but in my opinion the risk is pretty low for an up to date system assuming the user doesn't intentionally download potentially malicious files (PDFs or even worse, executable files).

Comment: The script has since been removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in the page source, nested in an HTML table cell as:

```
<td width="194" height="34" class="poll_row_border" style="padding-left:4px;"><div align="right" class="tool_description">
                    "><ScRipT>alert(31337)</ScrIpT>                </div></td>
```

Interestingly, there are two sets of similar code that contain this further down in the page source that also contain the Javascript code.  This indicates to me that several revisions to the site have been made with that code in place.  However, according to the WayBackMachine (http://web.archive.org/web/20150315142223/http://www.myplan.com/), the source on March 14th does NOT contain this Javascript.

As mentioned in the comments, this can still be an XSS attack called a persistent XSS attack since it is lodged in the actual source code.  This also isn't a security risk for you if you have no sensitive info stored at that site... for now.  If this is the product of an exploited XSS hole, it is acting as a beacon calling attention to any hackers browsing the site, letting them know that a vulnerability exists.  If they can find and exploit it with intent to implement a 0-day or malicious redirect, this affects you and your users.